# Cannot assign SimpleLazyObject in my code

Tags: django

I want to insert 'FineModel' data on 'ODE_Marks_Model' inserting time.

## model.py

```
class ODE_Registation_Model(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(SubjectMaster,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ode = models.ForeignKey(ODE_List_Model,on_delete = models.CASCADE,verbose_name="which ode")
    exam_date = models.DateField()
    registration_date = models.DateField()

class ODE_Marks_Model(models.Model):
    ode_registered =  models.OneToOneField(ODE_Registation_Model,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    marks = models.SmallIntegerField()
    verified_by = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class FineModel(models.Model):
    fine = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(ODE_Registation_Model,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

## admin.py

```
@admin.register(ODE_Marks_Model)
class ODE_Marks_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('ode_registered','marks','verified_by')
    exclude = ['verified_by',]

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        if instance.marks == -1:
            fine = FineModel.objects.create(user=request.user,fine=50)
            fine.save()
        instance.verified_by = request.user
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

I expect the output to save FineModel object in save_model but, I got the error :

> ValueError at /admin/core/ode_marks_model/add/ Cannot assign
>   ">": "FineModel.user" must be a
>   "ODE_Registation_Model" instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is raising from this line:

```
fine = FineModel.objects.create(user=request.user,fine=50)
```

In your model you have declined:

```
class FineModel(models.Model):
    fine = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(ODE_Registation_Model,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # your user part is ForeignKey for  different model but 
    # not built in User model
```

the `request.user` is an instance of built-in

```
django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

model.

So you cannot assign `request.user` to a field which is *ForeignKey* for `ODE_Registation_Model` model.